# How to move comment to new file with awk/sed/perl/etc.?

Tags: perl, awk, sed, extract

I want to extract comment from SCSS file put them on a new markdown file and remove the comments from original file.

### file.scss

```
/***
 * # Typography

 * We use
 * [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)
 */

/**
 * Body typography:
 * `p`
 *
 *     @example
 *     p This is a paragraph with #[strong bold ]&nbsp;and#[em italic ]&nbsp;styles.</p>
*/
body {
  color: $base-font-color;
}

/**
 * Heading 1:
 * `h1` `.h1`
 */
h1,
.h1 {
  @include h1;
}
```

### Expected result

At the end of the process I would like to have:

#### Comments.md

```
# Typography

* We use
[Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)

 Body typography:
 `p`

     @example
     p This is a paragraph with #[strong bold ]&nbsp;and#[em italic ]&nbsp;styles.</p>

  Heading 1:
 `h1` `.h1`
```

#### file.scss

```
body {
  color: $base-font-color;
}

h1,
.h1 {
  @include h1;
}
```

#### Question

How can I do that with `awk`, `perl`, `sed` or other tools?

Answer (score -2):

I implement a solution myself

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# USAGE
#   ## Development
#
#      # single file
#      bash ./scripts/extract-md.bash src/base/_typography.scss
#
#      # all files
#      bash ./scripts/extract-md.bash src/base/_typography.scss
#
#   ## production (override files)
#
#      export PRODUCTION=true
#      bash ./scripts/extract-md.bash

shopt -s globstar

start() {
  for legacy in $legacies; do
    directory="${legacy%/*}"
    filename="${legacy##*/}"

    new_filename="${filename//.scss/.md}"
    documentation="${directory}/${new_filename}"
    extract_comment "$legacy" "$documentation"

    stylesheet="${1//.scss/.new.scss}"
    extract_code "$legacy" "$stylesheet"
    [[ $PRODUCTION ]] && mv "$stylesheet" "$legacy"
  done
}

extract_comment() {
  local legacy="$1"
  local documentation="$2"
  awk '/^\/\*/{flag=1} flag; /^\s?\*\//{print;flag=0}' "$legacy" \
  | perl -p -e 's/\/[\*]+//g' \
  | perl -p -e 's/^\s*[\*]?[ \/]?//g' \
  > "$documentation"
}

extract_code() {
  local legacy="$1"
  local stylesheet="$2"
  awk 'BEGIN{flag=1}/^\/\*/{flag=0}; /^\s?\*\//{flag=1; next}flag' "$legacy" \
  > "$stylesheet"
}

legacies=${1:-src/**/*.scss}
start $legacies
```